# setState() is not recognizing in the statefulWidget class

Tags: flutter

```
class DataItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  String number;

  void setNumber(String nu){
    setState(() {
      this.number=nu;
    });
  }

  _DataItemState createState() => new _DataItemState(this.number);
}

class _DataItemState extends State<DataItem> {
  @override

  String number;

  _DataItemState(this.number);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: Text(
          number,
        style: TextStyle(...),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Please note that I am getting setState() is not defined with the above setup in the StatefulWidget (DataItem) however what I want to be done is following according to the attached screenshot. Once I pressed the button I need to update the labels accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to export functions which will change state.

This is a simple counter example but you should be able to perform more complex state changes with this.

https://dartpad.dev/6d43e30eb6febfcf7ad0eec8555035db

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is inside the class `State`, not inside the `StatefulWidget` class, you can do the following:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter = 0;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              counter.toString(),
            ),
           RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
             setState(() {
               counter++;
             });
          },
          child: Text(
            'Button',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
          ),
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will increment `counter` on every click

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what I need is a single button for all the TextWidget update and not for each TextWidget.

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b956f2427f0e2efffc363e65272a583f

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `setState` is only used in the state class of an `StatefulWidget`.

In second place, You don't need to use `setState` for values received via constructor all you need to do is to pass it to your widget.

Try this code:

```
class DataItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String number;

  const DataItem(this.number) : assert(number != null);

  _DataItemState createState() => _DataItemState();
}

class _DataItemState extends State<DataItem> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        widget.number,
        style: TextStyle(...),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

If you are not going to change the `number` property you can use `StatelessWidget`:

```
class DataItem extends StatelessWIdget {
  final String number;

  const DataItem(this.number) : assert(number != null);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        number,
        style: TextStyle(...),
      )
    );
  }
}
```